# Android circular reveal animation too fast

Tags: android, animation, view, circularreveal

I am using the circular reveal animation in my project, but it is now working correctly. The problem is the reveal happens way to fast and you almost can't see the reveal because it expands like instantly. I tried setting `anim.setDuration()` but that did not change anything. I used the code from the google examples.

Here my code:
    View myView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.view_to_expand);

```
int cx = myView.getRight();
int cy = myView.getBottom();

int finalRadius = Math.max(myView.getWidth(), myView.getHeight());

Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(myView, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);

myView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
anim.start();
```

`view_to_expand` is a simple relativelayout, don't think the problem is there. Also how can I apply the circular reveal to animation transitions?

Comment: I had similar problem, turned out i had animations turned off in developer options.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The instantaneous expansion is because there is some other heavy work on main thread aside from your animation (data update, other views/fragments hiding, render refresh and so on).

Best bet is to wrap it into a runnable and add it to the stack. It will be called when there is available CPU cycle and will show your animation.

Below is the **right** way to create and use your runnable. Try not to post an anonymous one since there is possibility user to return and your runnable to hang and expose a memory leak and/or to throw a runtime exception.

I presume here your class where your view stays is an activity and your `myView` is an instance reference in your activity

```
public final ApplicationActivity extends Activity {
    private View myView;

    private final Runnable revealAnimationRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int cx = myView.getRight();
            int cy = myView.getBottom();

            int finalRadius = Math.max(myView.getWidth(), myView.getHeight());
            Animator animator = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(myView, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);
            animator.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        myView = findViewById(R.id.view_to_expand);
        myView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        myView.post(revealAnimationRunnable);
        // alternatively, in case load is way too big, you can post with delay
        // i.e. comment above line and uncomment the one below
        // myView.postDelayed(revealAnimationRunnable, 200);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        ...
        myView.removeCallbacks(revealAnimationRunnable);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, will try that out. Also there is a typo in @Overrid :)

Comment: @Dimitar Genov I tried this and this works the first time.But from second time onwords it runs fast again.Sir is there any way i can solve this.

Comment: @user2217535 Have you tried with a slight delay, i.e. `myView.postDelayed(revealAnimationRunnable, 200)`? I would need some source to look at, there are way too many scenarios for this to fail - e.g. show/hide your fragment rather recreating it the second time, your runnable is not executed the second time you are opening the fragment, your view is still not attached and so on

Comment: @Dimitar Genov I tried with delay but its not working , actually I have been trying to switch two linear layout using this animation.From your comment I get that it can be fixed using a fragment and changed my layouts to fragment..........Now it works great .........,Thank you for your support sir.